# How do I join two or more Wordpress RSS Feeds?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

I have two Wordpress blogs installed separately and I want to join its RSS Feeds into one.

I've found this way: http://theos.in/technology/howto-combine-two-wordpress-rss-feed/ and it works but it's too slow to use.

There is a simple and fast way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a good solution!

The script was running slow because I wasn't using cache correctly.
You can set a cache timeout to use the generated Feed RSS in Feed Creator. You just have to set the same parameters for saveFeed...

```
$rss->saveFeed("RSS2.0", $TMP_ROOT."/rsscache/feed.xml");
```

... on useCached

```
$rss->useCached("RSS2.0", $TMP_ROOT."/rsscache/feed.xml", 3600); //1 hour reload
```

Then you call useCached before start creating a new version of that RSS Feed.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Yahoo Pipes](https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) as a way to do this. In short, you can mashup several feeds into a single one.  They have a [short tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3tS_DkmbVA) and it's pretty easy to use.